# Error parsing JSON data - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting the error below in Chrome while parsing a JSON data. The data sample is at http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=31ffc7c0e7e1a9a2adf641306497b57a This is a valid JSON and my server is sending the correct `Content-Type` value (`application/json`).

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Firefox reports a slightly different message but it all points to the presence of the period (`.`) in the beginning of the content.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 6 of the JSON data
```

I've tried both `$.parseJSON()` and `JSON.parse()` methods.

What's the cause of this error? Please enlighten.

I've read the other similar posts here, but they refer to a different character like `<`, etc.,

**EDIT:** This is the piece of code I'm using to retrieve the server data.

```
    $.ajax({
           url : searchUrl
    }).done(function(data) {
         var json_array = JSON.parse(data); // Apparently data is already JSON parsed.
   });
```

Comment: That data gives no error messages in Chrome, do you have an example of the actual problem?

Comment: I can't view the page from your link at work, but this usually indicates that the data you are feeding to `JSON.parse()` and `$.parseJSON()` is indeed __not__ valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data probably is already an object, try it without `$.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()` and it should work.

Comment: Ah! I'm using JQuery's `$.ajax()` to retrieve the data. How do you parse the data from it? It's nothing but an array of strings.

Comment: `result[0]` would give you the first one.

Comment: Rudi, silly me! But thanks very much! What I don't understand is how I already got the parsed JSON object. I've added some snippet in case you're curious.

Comment: @asgs jQuery does that for you: _The type of pre-processing depends by default upon the Content-Type of the response ... If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed_ [all details here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Rudi, got it. Thanks again! I'll never ever forget the message `Unexpected token .` again.